# Magnetic charging

Tags: wireless, charging, electromagnetic, inductive

I have a question about magnetically charging devices and would like to see if anyone can help.

I understand we have things like cell phone chargers that wirelessly charge using inductive technology, but all of these charging devices must be actually plugged into the wall or be directly tied into a power source and then create a separate wireless charging system.

I'm wondering if there is a way to grab power from current passing through a conductor using a clamp-on style device. I'm trying to see if there is a way to charge a really small/low current device without actually connecting it to wires our an outlet. So, kind of like a reverse version of what I see so much.

Comment: A possibly relevant technical reference: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidud59/tidud59.pdf

Comment: Yes **but**: the conductors must be separated, which is not very common and the amount of power you'd get with a clamp-on device is probably in the microwatts range.

Comment: For AC wiring, read about [Current Transformers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_transformer).  Instead of a burden resistor, you want a load of some kind.  CT's will only work when there is current flowing through the AC wire, and they will not work at DC.

Comment: There are some electricity monitors that clamp round a (single strand) cable, and draw all of their low operating power from the cable itself, via their current transformer. They contain rechargable batteries as well, so continue to work when the current is low or absent.